# What is the difference between pickle and shelve?

Tags: python, pickle, shelve, object-serialization

When is it appropriate to use `pickle`, and when is it appropriate to use `shelve`? That is to say, what do they do differently from each other?

From my research, I understood that `pickle` can turn every Python object into stream of bytes which can be persisted into a file. Then why do we need `shelve` as well? Isn't `pickle` faster?

Comment: Is it like the case that pickle is like a very low-level stuff and shelve gives us more ways to store complex objects?

Comment: `shelve` provides a dictionary-style interface to pickling.  A dictionary interface to pickling is convenient for implementing things like caching of results (so you don't ever recalculate) -- the keys being `*args,**kwds` and the value being the calculated results.

Comment: Note that `shelve` *DOES NOT* enable one to store objects that `pickle` cannot pickle.  If you are looking for a better version of `shelve` that can both store the majority of python objects as well as provides a more flexible dictionary interface to disk or database… then you might want to look at `klepto`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32586980/2379433

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`pickle` is for serializing some object (or objects) as a single bytestream in a file.

`shelve` builds on top of `pickle` and implements a serialization dictionary where objects are pickled, but associated with a key (some string), so you can load your shelved data file and access your pickled objects via keys. This could be more convenient were you to be serializing many objects.

Here is an example of usage between the two. (should work in latest versions of Python 2.7 and Python 3.x).

### `pickle` Example

```
import pickle

integers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

with open('pickle-example.p', 'wb') as pfile:
    pickle.dump(integers, pfile)
```

This will dump the `integers` list to a binary file called `pickle-example.p`.

Now try reading the pickled file back.

```
import pickle

with open('pickle-example.p', 'rb') as pfile:
    integers = pickle.load(pfile)
    print(integers)
```

The above should output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

### `shelve` Example

```
import shelve

integers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# If you're using Python 2.7, import contextlib and use
# the line:
# with contextlib.closing(shelve.open('shelf-example', 'c')) as shelf:
with shelve.open('shelf-example', 'c') as shelf:
    shelf['ints'] = integers
```

Notice how you add objects to the shelf via dictionary-like access.

Read the object back in with code like the following:

```
import shelve

# If you're using Python 2.7, import contextlib and use
# the line:
# with contextlib.closing(shelve.open('shelf-example', 'r')) as shelf:
with shelve.open('shelf-example', 'r') as shelf:
    for key in shelf.keys():
        print(repr(key), repr(shelf[key]))
```

The output will be `'ints', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Can you shed some light on what the 'c' flag is for in the call to `shelve.open`? I googled but could not find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @aniketd the `'c'` flag tells `shelve` to open the file for reading and writing, or to create the file if needed. It's also described in [`shelve.open`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html), which shares the same flags as [`anydbm.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html#anydbm.open).

Comment: @birryree What version of Python does your example work with? On 2.7.10, it's indicating that there is no Context Manager implemented for shelve: `----> 5 with shelve.open('shelf-example-file.txt', 'c') as shelf:
      6     for k, v in my_dict:
      7         shelf[k] = v

AttributeError: DbfilenameShelf instance has no attribute '__exit__'`

Comment: @Pyderman I must have verified my code in 3.x but not 2.7.x, probably assuming context manager usage wouldn't be different between them. I updated my examples to say that if you're using Python 2.7, you should `import contextlib` in your code and then wrap your `shelve.open` with `contextlib.closing()`.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a paragraph about when to prefer which, and whether pickle is actually significantly faster

Comment: This answer fails to explain: why not just **build the dictionary** and store it with Pickle (since it can serialize dictionaries)? To my understanding, the actual reason (shown by the code, but not addressed in the explanation) is that you can work with the shelf "as a dictionary" *while the underlying file is still open*, and without reading the whole thing in to memory. That is to say, `shelve` doesn't have separate `dump`/`load` steps; access is provided *by opening* the shelf.

Answer (score 10):

According to [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) documentation:

> Serialization is a more primitive notion than persistence; although **pickle** reads and writes file objects, it does not handle the issue of naming persistent objects, nor the (even more complicated) issue of concurrent access to persistent objects. The **pickle** module can transform a complex object into a byte stream and it can transform the byte stream into an object with the same internal structure. Perhaps the most obvious thing to do with these byte streams is to write them onto a file, but it is also conceivable to send them across a network or store them in a database. The **shelve** module provides a simple interface to pickle and unpickle objects on DBM-style database files.