# Pickle versus shelve storing large dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, pickle, shelve

If I am storing a large directory as a `pickle` file, does loading it via `cPickle` mean that it will all be consumed into memory at once?

If so, is there a cross platform way to get something like `pickle`, but access each entry one key at a item (i.e. avoid loading all of the dictionary into memory and only load each entry by name)? I know `shelve` is supposed to do this: is that as portable as `pickle` though?

Comment: pickle is a security vunerability

Comment: the contents end up getting exec'd (or eval'd) when it unpacks it

Comment: `shelve` uses some flavor of DBM database to store pickled objects. It should be at least as portable as `pickle`.

Comment: While @JoranBeasley is technically correct, pickles are enormously useful and safe *when you write them yourself*. DO NOT accept pickles from untrusted sources, but it's OK to use them for serialization of your own data.

Comment: @JoranBeasley `shelve` is also prone to the same security vulnerabilities as `pickle`, since it's backed by `pickle`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I know shelve is supposed to do this: is that as portable as pickle though?

Yes. [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) is part of [The Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/) and is written in Python.

#### Edit

So if you have a large dictionary:

```
bigd = {'a': 1, 'b':2, # . . .
}
```

And you want to save it without having to read the whole thing in later then don't save it as a pickle, it would be better to save it as a shelf, a sort of on disk dictionary.

```
import shelve

myShelve = shelve.open('my.shelve')
myShelve.update(bigd)
myShelve.close()
```

Then later you can:

```
import shelve

myShelve = shelve.open('my.shelve')
value = myShelve['a']
value += 1
myShelve['a'] = value
```

You basically treat the shelve object like a dict, but the items are stored on disk (as individual pickles) and read in as needed.

If your objects could be stored as a list of properties, then [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) may be a good alternative. Shelves and pickles are convenient, but can only be accessed by Python, but a sqlite database can by read from most languages.

Comment: So is it true that pickle loads all pickled objects into memory always?

Comment: Shelve not cross platform

Comment: Don't you need to close the shelf to have the changes flush to disk?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, the Python 2.x documentation specifically says: "Like file objects, shelve objects should be closed explicitly to ensure that the persistent data is flushed to disk." See https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html

Comment: The answer to _"is that as portable as pickle?"_ is **No**. For example, on my machine it chooses to be backed by `dbhash`. If I make a DB file and move it to another machine, where `dbhash` is not available, `shelve.open(..)` will fail on that file. The only portable pure-Python option currently is `dumbdbm`. To make a portable shelf, it needs to be set up to use `dumbdbm` explicitly (which is not the default).

Answer (score 10):

If you want a module that's more robust than `shelve`, you might look at `klepto`.  `klepto` is built to provide a dictionary interface to platform-agnostic storage on disk or database, and is built to work with large data.

Here, we first create some pickled objects stored on disk. They use the `dir_archive`, which stores one object per file.

```
>>> d = dict(zip('abcde',range(5)))
>>> d['f'] = max
>>> d['g'] = lambda x:x**2
>>> 
>>> import klepto
>>> help(klepto.archives.dir_archive)       

>>> print klepto.archives.dir_archive.__new__.__doc__
initialize a dictionary with a file-folder archive backend

    Inputs:
        name: name of the root archive directory [default: memo]
        dict: initial dictionary to seed the archive
        cached: if True, use an in-memory cache interface to the archive
        serialized: if True, pickle file contents; otherwise save python objects
        compression: compression level (0 to 9) [default: 0 (no compression)]
        memmode: access mode for files, one of {None, 'r+', 'r', 'w+', 'c'}
        memsize: approximate size (in MB) of cache for in-memory compression

>>> a = klepto.archives.dir_archive(dict=d)
>>> a
dir_archive('memo', {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'g': <function <lambda> at 0x102f562a8>, 'f': <built-in function max>}, cached=True)
>>> a.dump()
>>> del a
```

Now, the data is all on disk, let's pick and choose which ones we want to load in to memory. `b` is the dict in memory, while `b.archive` maps the collection of files into a dictionary view.

```
>>> b = klepto.archives.dir_archive('memo')
>>> b
dir_archive('memo', {}, cached=True)
>>> b.keys()   
[]
>>> b.archive.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f']
>>> b.load('a')
>>> b
dir_archive('memo', {'a': 0}, cached=True)
>>> b.load('b')
>>> b.load('f')
>>> b.load('g')
>>> b['g'](b['f'](b['a'],b['b']))
1
```

`klepto` also provides the same interface to a `sql` archive.

```
>>> print klepto.archives.sql_archive.__new__.__doc__
initialize a dictionary with a sql database archive backend

    Connect to an existing database, or initialize a new database, at the
    selected database url. For example, to use a sqlite database 'foo.db'
    in the current directory, database='sqlite:///foo.db'. To use a mysql
    database 'foo' on localhost, database='mysql://user:pass@localhost/foo'.
    For postgresql, use database='postgresql://user:pass@localhost/foo'. 
    When connecting to sqlite, the default database is ':memory:'; otherwise,
    the default database is 'defaultdb'. If sqlalchemy is not installed,
    storable values are limited to strings, integers, floats, and other
    basic objects. If sqlalchemy is installed, additional keyword options
    can provide database configuration, such as connection pooling.
    To use a mysql or postgresql database, sqlalchemy must be installed.

    Inputs:
        name: url for the sql database [default: (see note above)]
        dict: initial dictionary to seed the archive
        cached: if True, use an in-memory cache interface to the archive
        serialized: if True, pickle table contents; otherwise cast as strings

>>> c = klepto.archives.sql_archive('database')
>>> c.update(b)
>>> c
sql_archive('sqlite:///database', {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'g': <function <lambda> at 0x10446b1b8>, 'f': <built-in function max>}, cached=True)
>>> c.dump()
```

Where now the same objects on disk are also in a sql archive.  We can add new objects to either archive.

```
>>> b['x'] = 69
>>> c['y'] = 96
>>> b.dump('x')
>>> c.dump('y')
```

Get `klepto` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: Note that I'm the author of `klepto`