# How to Persist class Instances using klepto

Tags: python-3.x, klepto

I'm trying klepto as a replacement for shelve to persist class instances but am seeing a lengthy traceback when attempting to do so.

My platform is:
python 3.7.3
klepto 0.1.6

The example @
[Pickle versus shelve storing large dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668475/pickle-versus-shelve-storing-large-dictionaries-in-python) 
... works fine on the above platform.

```
from   dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass (frozen=True)
class Target:
    name : str
@dataclass (frozen=True)
class Image:
    target :Target

image_1 = Image (target=Target(name='Crab Nebula'))
image_2 = Image (target=Target(name='Orion Nebula'))
##keys = image_1.name, image_2.name
keys = image_1.target.name, image_2.target.name
values = image_1, image_2
d = dict ( zip (keys,values))
import klepto
a = klepto.archives.dir_archive (dict=d)
a.dump()
```

a.dump() initiates a lengthy traceback beginning with ...

```
File "C:\Users\jgv\Documents\Projects\AstroPix_ODB (klepto)\stackoverflow.py", line 20, in <module>
   a.dump()
 File "C:\Users\jgv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\klepto\_archives.py", line 165, in dump
   self.archive.update(self)
```

and concluding with ...

```
 File "C:\Users\jgv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 1148, in save_dictproxy
   raise ReferenceError("%s does not reference a class __dict__" % obj)
ReferenceError: {} does not reference a class __dict__
```

Comment: FWIW removing the @dataclass decorators and defining the classes in un-decorated fashion works.

Comment: Hi I'm the `klepto` author. The reason you are seeing that error is that `dill` doesn't know how to serialize a `dataclass` .  So, if you use an `serialized=False` archive, or some other `protocol`, such as `json` or `fast=True`, you can successfully `dump` the object.  There are a lot of format variants available in `klepto`.  Looks like, regardless, there are still some failures on `load`.  Can you report this to the `klepto` GitHub page?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Mike.  An issue "dill doesn't know how to serialize @dataclass instances" has been submitted on the klepto GitHub page.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is a solution.  I think there's a second issue... `klepto` appears to botching the non-serialized attempt to store the object as well. Could you also report failure to dump/load the object when using `serialized=False`?  BTW: using whitespace in a key's name is not a good idea unless you plan on encoding the key.

Comment: I see, you reported the `dill` issue to `klepto`.  No worries.  I adjusted issues accordingly.

Comment: Could you clarify why keys with (embedded) white-space are a bad idea?  The actual keys are "pre-treated" to strip leading/trailing white-space and reduce all embedded multi-space to single-space.  Does klepto support non-string keys (i.e., hash-able class instances)?

Comment: Jim, it depending on the key encoding.  Some keys are encoded to hashes, some to compact sequences with no whitespace, some serialized objects, and others are treated as mildly-mangled strings. So, yes, the `dir_archive` with a particular encoding could set the name of the file to something with a embedded whitespace, which wouldn't be good.  Other encodings wouldn't care.