# Can you permanently change python code by input?

Tags: python

I'm still learning python and am currently developing an API (artificial personal assistant e.g. Siri or Cortana). I was wondering if there was a way to update code by input. For example, if I had a list- would it be possible to PERMANENTLY add a new item even after the program has finished running.

I read that you would have to use SQLite, is that true? And are there any other ways?

Comment: This is an XY problem. You do not want to change code, you are looking for a way to persist data between running the program.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello J Nowak**

I think what you want to do is save the input data to a file (Eg. txt file).
You can view the link below which will show you how to read and write to a text file.

[How to read and write to text file in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are planty of methods how you can make your data persistent.
It depends on the task, on the environment etc.
Just a couple examples:

- Files (JSON, DBM, Pickle)
- NoSQL Databases (Redis, MongoDB, etc.)
- SQL Databases (both serverless and client server: sqlite, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.)

The most simple/basic approach is to use files. 
There are even modules that allow to do it transparently.
You just work with your data as always.

See `shelve` for example.

From the documentation:

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object. The difference with
>   “dbm” databases is that the values (not the keys!) in a shelf can be
>   essentially arbitrary Python objects — anything that the pickle module
>   can handle. This includes most class instances, recursive data types,
>   and objects containing lots of shared sub-objects. The keys are
>   ordinary strings.

Example of usage:

```
import shelve

s = shelve.open('test_shelf.db')
try:
    s['key1'] = { 'int': 10, 'float':9.5, 'string':'Sample data' }
finally:
    s.close()
```

You work with `s` just normally, as it were just a normal dictionary.
And it is automatically saved on disk (in file `test_shelf.db` in this case).

In this case your dictionary is persistent
and will not lose its values after the program restart.

More on it:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html
- https://pymotw.com/2/shelve/

Another option is to use pickle, which gives you persistence
also, but not magically: you will need read and write data on your own.

Comparison between `shelve` and `pickle`:

- [What is the difference between pickle and shelve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103430/what-is-the-difference-between-pickle-and-shelve)