# How to extract text from lxml.etree tags based on value of sibling tags

Tags: python, lxml

My objective is to pull urls from an xml document (linked) and put them in a list:
https://www.valuespreadsheet.com/iedgar/results.php?stock=NFLX&output=xml

I imported `etree` from `lxml` and created a list comprehension that pulls the text from all `<instanceUrl>` tags.

```
url = 'https://valuespreadsheet.com/iedgar/results.php?stock=NFLX&output=xml' 
et = etree.fromstring(urlopen(url).read())
return [_.find('instanceUrl').text for _ in et.find('filings')]
```

Now, I want to restrict the list so that it only pulls the text from `<instanceUrl>` tags where `<formType>`=10K.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845273/can-you-permanently-change-python-code-by-input?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an [XPath expression and the `xpath()` method](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) :

```
[url.text for url in et.xpath('//filing[formType = "10-K"]/instanceUrl')]
```

Here we are filtering the `filing` nodes that contain `formType` child nodes with `10-K` text, then getting the `instanceUrl` child.

Note that the `_` variable name is used for *throw-away variables* - variables that have to be defined but not actually used (e.g. during unpacking). In your case, you've actually used it.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, explanation, and advice on how `_` variable name is used!